# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.game.mrnom.MrNomGame loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader [/data/app/com.game.mrnom-1.apk]

Tags: java, android, classnotfoundexception

In my title, MrNomGame is a java file in com.game.mrnom folder (of src folder).
When I run my app, Android Emulator error: `The application has stopped unexpectedly.`
When I view logCat, there are many errors. and above error is one of the first lines of logCat and directly tell about my error. 
Here is also  my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.game.mrnom"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application

        android:debuggable="true" 
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="Mr.Nom" >


        <activity
            android:label="Mr.Nom Own"
            android:name="com.game.mrnom.MrNomGame"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="8" android:minSdkVersion="8"/>

</manifest>
```

I google and someone say that ADB bug when I refactor:rename a package (and I have tried this sometimes). but I still cannot fix it.

Help me about this error,please.

thanks :)

Here my error logcat:

> 02-11 21:12:46.858: D/AndroidRuntime(276): Shutting down VM 02-11 
>   21:12:46.858: W/dalvikvm(276): threadid=1: thread exiting with
>   uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
>
> 02-11 21:12:46.958: E/AndroidRuntime(276): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> 02-11 21:12:46.958: E/AndroidRuntime(276): java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.game.mrnom/com.game.mrnom.MrNomGame}:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.game.mrnom.MrNomGame in loader
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.game.mrnom-1.apk]
>
> 02-11 21:12:46.958: E/AndroidRuntime(276):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
>
> 02-11 21:12:46.958: E/AndroidRuntime(276):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
>
> 02-11 21:12:46.958: E/AndroidRuntime(276):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
>
> 02-11 21:12:46.958: E/AndroidRuntime(276):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
>
> 02-11 21:12:46.958: E/AndroidRuntime(276):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 02-11
>   21:12:46.958: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>
> 02-11 21:12:46.958: E/AndroidRuntime(276):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
>
> 02-11 21:12:46.958: E/AndroidRuntime(276):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>
> 02-11 21:12:46.958: E/AndroidRuntime(276):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>
> 02-11 21:12:46.958: E/AndroidRuntime(276):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>
> 02-11 21:12:46.958: E/AndroidRuntime(276):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
>
> 02-11 21:12:46.958: E/AndroidRuntime(276):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>
> 02-11 21:12:46.958: E/AndroidRuntime(276): Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.game.mrnom.MrNomGame in loader
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.game.mrnom-1.apk]
>
> 02-11 21:12:46.958: E/AndroidRuntime(276):    at
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
>
> 02-11 21:12:46.958: E/AndroidRuntime(276):    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
>
> 02-11 21:12:46.958: E/AndroidRuntime(276):    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
>
> 02-11 21:12:46.958: E/AndroidRuntime(276):    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
>
> 02-11 21:12:46.958: E/AndroidRuntime(276):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
>
> 02-11 21:12:46.958: E/AndroidRuntime(276):    ... 11 more
>
> 02-11 21:12:54.277: I/Process(276): Sending signal. PID: 276 SIG: 9
>
> 02-11 21:12:58.157: D/AndroidRuntime(284): Shutting down VM
>
> 02-11 21:12:58.157: W/dalvikvm(284): threadid=1: thread exiting with
>   uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
>
> 02-11 21:12:58.207: E/AndroidRuntime(284): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> 02-11 21:12:58.207: E/AndroidRuntime(284): java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.game.mrnom/com.game.mrnom.MrNomGame}:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.game.mrnom.MrNomGame in loader
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.game.mrnom-1.apk]
>
> 02-11 21:12:58.207: E/AndroidRuntime(284):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
>
> 02-11 21:12:58.207: E/AndroidRuntime(284):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
>
> 02-11 21:12:58.207: E/AndroidRuntime(284):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
>
> 02-11 21:12:58.207: E/AndroidRuntime(284):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
>
> 02-11 21:12:58.207: E/AndroidRuntime(284):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>
> 02-11 21:12:58.207: E/AndroidRuntime(284):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>
> 02-11 21:12:58.207: E/AndroidRuntime(284):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627) 02-11
>   21:12:58.207: E/AndroidRuntime(284):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>
> 02-11 21:12:58.207: E/AndroidRuntime(284):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>
> 02-11 21:12:58.207: E/AndroidRuntime(284):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>
> 02-11 21:12:58.207: E/AndroidRuntime(284):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
>
> 02-11 21:12:58.207: E/AndroidRuntime(284):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>
> 02-11 21:12:58.207: E/AndroidRuntime(284): Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.game.mrnom.MrNomGame in loader
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.game.mrnom-1.apk]
>
> 02-11 21:12:58.207: E/AndroidRuntime(284):    at
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
>
> 02-11 21:12:58.207: E/AndroidRuntime(284):    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
>
> 02-11 21:12:58.207: E/AndroidRuntime(284):    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
>
> 02-11 21:12:58.207: E/AndroidRuntime(284):    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
>
> 02-11 21:12:58.207: E/AndroidRuntime(284):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
>
> 02-11 21:12:58.207: E/AndroidRuntime(284):    ... 11 more 02-11
>   21:17:58.297: I/Process(284): Sending signal. PID: 284 SIG: 9

Comment: can you please add your log errors so that we can get more out of it

Comment: you are missing jar file... please check what you have in your library files...

Comment: @Fahim Parker: can you tell me more, please.
Some other android projects I try still can run. but not this :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your error in manifest you should say

```
<activity
            android:label="Mr.Nom Own"
            android:name=".MrNomOwn" <<<same name of your activity (case sensitive)
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

edit :
you need to put constructor in your MrNomOwn activity as this :

```
public MrNomOwn(){

super();

}
```

Comment: Yes. the previous version of com.game.mrnom.MrNomGame is .MrNomGame. and still meet same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line in your Manifest

```
 android:name="com.game.mrnom.MrNomGame"
```

to

```
android:name=".MrNomGame"
```

Comment: Yes. the previous version of  `com.game.mrnom.MrNomGame` is `.MrNomGame`. and still meet same problem.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and running again? If problem still exists you can paste your Log Cat Errors.

Comment: @hqt : You still havent changed the android:name to .MrNomGame ...you have this declared in your manifest tag >>package="com.game.mrnom" ...so this error is showing up java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.game.mrnom/com.game.mrnom.MrNomGame}..Change your android:name to .MrNomGame and Clean and Run

Answer (score 0):

every screen in your project must have an entry in your manifest file.  It should look something like this:

```
    <activity   
        android:label="Game Screen"
        android:name=".GameScreen"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" />
```

I hope this works I'm still having trouble with mine.